# How to install libyaml-devel on "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4"

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat, libyaml

Can someone help me to install libyaml-devel?

I am using below command

```
yum install libyaml-devel
```

but i am getting "No package libyaml-devel available." error

Answer (score 1):

you can add new repository to your OS

OR

you can download the rpm package of it from :

```
https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libyaml-devel&submit=Search+...&system=centos&arch=
```

and install it with :

```
rpm -ivh PKG_NAME
```